# Regex for 3 C + string + C in java

Tags: java, regex

I am looking for the regex for the below:

IICCCIIC should return CCCIIC.
IICCIC should fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find "[^C]*(C{3}[^C]+C)" replace with "$1"

This discards any characters on the front of the string until there is a C ([^C]*). Then we look for 3 Cs in a row (C{3}) followed by one or more characters that are not a C ([^C]+) followed by the final C (C). The brackets in the original expression are used to "capture" the string after the initial characters are discarded, and we refer to this capture in the replace statement, using "$1".

Comment: @olambert would you please explain the details of the RegEx?

Comment: I've edited my answer to explain each part of the regex